# Get value after last comma in CSV file in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Note: I tried using `d3js` but I accept any other usage model, getting the expected value any method will be positive for me.

Example to file `./Lista_de_Jogos.csv`:

```
a,b,c,d,e,1
f,g,h,i,j,2
```

I would always like to collect the last value of the `CSV` regardless of its size, in this example the value would be:

```
2
```

My attempt was:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.1.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-fetch@3"></script>

<script>
   function lastvalue() {
      let lastvalue = d3.csv("./Lista_de_Jogos.csv");
      var lastvaluelast = lastvalue.substr(lastvalue.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
      console.log("Last Value: ", {lastvaluelast})
   }
</script>
```

But I can't get the return of the value, how should I proceed to receive such value?

I've already searched on stackoverflow and couldn't find an example for `Javascript/HTML`

Comment: Why cant u get the desired value? What errors are shown?

Comment: Good night friend @testing_22 , the value is simply not delivered in DevTools. I couldn't understand what might be happening.

Comment: you need to use promise because it makes a HTTP req and that is not instataneous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the promise to resolve. Use `then`:

```
function lastvalue() {
    d3.csv("./list.csv").then(result => {
        console.log('result:', result)
        const lastRow = result[result.length - 1]
        console.log('lastRow:', lastRow)
        const lastValue = lastRow[result.columns[result.columns.length - 1]]
        console.log('lastValue:', lastValue)
    });
}

lastvalue()
```

Comment: Hi @stoin, the error in my test for your tip is ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: lastvalue.substr is not a function```

Comment: That's because the returned value of `lastvalue` is a list, not a string. This is what it returns: https://i.imgur.com/h1ULMOX.png

Comment: Hi @Clvckl3s but my need was the last value in the file (```2```), I had figured that the tip would be for that. I'm sorry if I didn't understand!

Comment: Hi @BrondbyIF. Yes, the result from d3 was not in the shape you expected. I updated my answer - I think it will work for you now.

Comment: Hi @Stoen Perfect friend, thank you very much and I'm sorry for the basic doubts that I couldn't keep up with, I'm learning and I still have difficulties with javascript/html